# How to filter blocked attachments from exchange by ews

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

When I use the [GetItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa566013(v=exchg.150).aspx) operation to get email attachments, I get all attachments including those which are need to be blocked by exchange.

There is also a [list of blocked attachments](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Blocked-attachments-in-Outlook-3811cddc-17c3-4279-a30c-060ba0207372?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) but it is just the default. Exchange admins can add or remove extensions by editing the registry.

Is there a way to filter the attachments that need to be blocked ?

Answer (score 0):

No this is done at the application level so Outlook and OWA have their own method of doing it (and allowing bypassing). At the API level EWS or MAPI there is no restriction (or property indicating an attachments should be blocked).